# C/C++ Visual Libraries

Tags: c++, c, image-processing

Are there any libraries for C and C++ which support (relatively) simple 2D recognition tasks? [by simple I mean little motion, fixed background, etc.)

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/166663).

Comment: Isn't better to use google for this?

Answer (score 2):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is probably your best choice but you'll still need a good understanding of how it all works!

Comment: very helpful - and, of course, you're right. but one thing at a time...

Comment: There are no shortages of examples for OpenCV, this might help too http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html